# A (Director's name) movie - why not possessive?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, possessives

I have just watched a movie and noticed, during the opening credits:

> A James Cameron movie

Why it is not "James Cameron's movie" when it actually is his film (in a sense that he directed it). Why his name is used as an adjective?

Comment: May be because James Cameron is famous... :)

Comment: It's **not** an adjective! James Cameron is a nominal modifying "movie". Compare "James Cameron's latest movie is awful."

Comment: @BillJ - I agree it's not an adjective. Would you agree that it's being used "adjectively"?

Comment: @J.R. No, because that might imply that it's an adjective, which it isn't, or imply that it has the properties of an adjective, which it hasn't. 'Modifier' is the correct term for dependents in a phrase that de-limit the meaning of the head word. Attributive modifiers in an NP may be AdjPs, DPs, VPs, and nominals (like the OP's). Post-head modifiers can be PPs, AdvPs, apppositive NPs, non-appositive NPs and clauses (both finite and non-finite) . Clearly we don't want to call them all adjectives, or imply that they are functioning as adjectives, hence the catch-all term 'modifier'.

Comment: @BillJ - We agree that [_modtifier_](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/modifier) is the better term, and that it's not an adjective. My question was about the word [_adjectively_](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/adjectively).

Comment: @J.R.  I think it is very unsatisfactory to have a function term that is morphologically derived from a category term. Modifier is a function term, not a category one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stylistic Convention (written and spoken)**

In English, the names of creators of a creative work (painting, drawing, movie, sculpture, cartoon, piece of music, song, etc., etc.) can be placed in front of the work to mean: the creative work created by that person.

- Beethoven symphony means: a symphony composed by Beethoven
- Picasso painting means: a painting painted by Picasso
- Miller play: a play written by (Arthur) Miller
- Giacometti sculpture: a sculpture sculpted by Giacometti
- Hitchcock movie: a movie directed by Hitchcock
- Mies building: a building designed by Mies (van der Rohe)

This is just usage. There is no grammatical explanation for it, really. I call this **a stylistic convention**: using a creator's name (proper noun) in front of the work to mean: the work created by a particular creator. Of course, you can use grammatical terms to describe it but it will not help you understand how to use it. (By that I mean: it will not help you understand that a Hitchcock movie is a movie directed by Hitchcock.)

If you were comparing two directors, you could say or write this one of two ways:

- The [this, that] Cameron movie is better than the [this, that] Hitchcock movie.

**Or**:

- Cameron's movie is better than Hitchcock's movie.

In critics' language, in written form, the name + noun form usually prevails, unless there is some specific reason for using the possessive, for clarity's sake, for example.

In the case of **Cameron's movie**, it is not really that it **belongs to him**, as if this were a weird possessive case, unless copyright to it is being discussed,for example.

**The meaning of the possessive in these cases** is : a movie directed by Cameron (likewise with other verbs for other creations: painted by, written by, composed by etc.) So the possessive is really used to mean: by. A Picasso painting is a painting [painted] **by** Picasso. **And not "of"**.

Also, beware of this: sometimes the name preceding the noun is not describing what I just said, but rather, it is used to **give a name to a physical place**: the John Hancock Building, a formal name, and not any building that long-departed man may have built. In the case of the Eiffel Tower, however, it is the place name and the name of the architect.

Comment: I'd only add that it's quite common to precede phrases like the ones you've listed with an indefinite article: _a Beethoven symphony, a Hitchcock movie, [a Mark Goodson Bill Todman production](http://image.wikifoundry.com/image/1/mMf0mSQRlOgQjOqwPrRFdQ41475)_.

Comment: @J.R. They can be a/the and plurals, but I was not going to cover every ancillary detail. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this phrase, *"James Cameron"* is an adjective describing the subject (*"movie"*); it is the same usage as, for example, *"A Paramount Pictures production"*.

It is also possible that the possessive form is avoided because "ownership" is not really intended to be in focus.

Comment: -1 for posting a wrong answer. How can it be an adjective? It's a nominal modifying "movie", just as "Paramount Pictures" is a nominal modifying "production" in your example. Adjectives are words like "tall", "thin", "latest". "long" and the like.

Comment: By most dictionary definitions and common usage, an adjective is a word or phrase that modifies a noun. That is exactly what is happening here. There may be niche terminology used specifically by linguists that says something else, but that only means that the word is being defined differently by them and that any debate is based on a definitional misunderstanding.

Comment: @JasonBassford It has nothing to do with linguistics. It is simple basic grammatical terminology. It is commonly accepted throughout the word of grammar that dictionaries are fine for meanings but not grammar. Would anyone seriously think that in, for example, the noun phrase "the person [for you to consult]", that the bracketed element is an adjective. Of course not; it's a non-finite clause serving as a post-head modifier.

Answer (score 0):

> *A James Cameron movie.*

"James Cameron" is not an adjective. It's a nominal modifying "movie".

Another decent example might be "a United States warship".

Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!

Comment: A Dickens novel, a Shakespeare play, a Beatles song.

Comment: How is this different from "James Cameron's movie?"

Comment: @JasonBassford _Modifier_ is the standard term for such elements. Not all words that modify nouns are classified as adjectives.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not disputing the word "modifier." I have a problem with questioning the use of "adjective" as the focus of the answer rather than addressing the actual question.

Comment: @JasonBassford The answer is clear. "James Cameron" is a nominal, i.e. the part of a noun phrase that excludes the determiner. Compare the non-modifying "James Cameron's latest movie is a flop" / "I love James Cameron's latest movie". (Notice the absence of a determiner in these genitive constructions.)

Comment: Genitive is "of" aka here, an apostrophe s. This is not: movie **of** James Cameron. It is:the movie **by** James Cameron. Ergo, it is an anomaly, grammar-wise and one calls it a genitive at one's own risk.